# How to simulate keyboard input at driver level in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, keyboard, kernel, driver, wdm

I want to make simple driver that will simulate keyboard input at driver level.
My first idea was to make simple kbdclass filter driver. But at this point I can't inject my input whenever I want(I need to wait for IRP and then change KEYBOARD_INPUT array).
Can somebody explain me how could it be done?
Also this need to be done in old manner (No kmdf at all).
Thanks!

Comment: *"Can someone help me with this stuff?"* is not a question that fits Stack Overflow. See [ask].

Comment: look for `IOCTL_INTERNAL_KEYBOARD_CONNECT` - save here `CONNECT_DATA` and call `KeyboardClassServiceCallback` yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the VHIDMini2 driver in the WDK